# GFCI tester shows fault, but everything is working

Tags: wiring, gfci, troubleshooting

I have a GFCI outlet and when the GFCI tester is plugged in, that shows this error code when it is tripped: greater than 30VAC, and open ground, open neutral.

I’ve replaced the GFCI, but I still get the error, so it looks like there is an issue with the wiring. The outlet works with no problems and when I trip the circuit, the power does goes off.  I only get the error code.  Any recommendations????

Comment: What tester are you using?

Comment: I suspect you are using an "intelligent" tester, combined with a hot/neutral reverse (or some other strange problem). Get a **simple** [Magic 8-Ball + GFCI](https://amzn.to/39M7BvS) tester and see what that shows. Need to know the lights before & after the GFCI test.

Comment: I used the Klein GFCI Receptacle Tester with LCD https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-GFCI-Receptacle-Tester-with-LCD-RT250/313832938.  Before test lights were green. After test it showed red with the error: open ground neutral with >30vac. Ok thanks, I’ll have to get the Magic 8 ball. Also hot/neutral is not reversed and line load wiring is correct.

Comment: The tester you used is a microprocessor controlled simulation of the magic 8 ball. No matter how well designed, it is more susceptible to phantom voltage and various other problems

Comment: There's a HUGE difference between "everything is working" and "everything is safe".  Many combinations of electrical wire hooks will work *and will kill you*.  That's why people (who don't know what they're doing) experimenting by trying different combinations of wires is a bad idea.  They are more likely to stumble onto a "works, but lethal" combo than a "works+safe" combo.

Comment: Thanks manassehkatz, will be checking it with the other tester.  Harper, All I can say is that the black (hot) is connected to the load, the neutral and ground are secured to the bar in the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### That tester.

Don't read too much into it.  It's a hokey-dokey tester.  They work in new construction with all new products and open walls, because that work only tends to see a few types of problems.  The product is tuned for that.  When troubleshooting old work, they are wrong *far more than they're right*.  That's bad because it send you on *wild goose chases* to hunt down a problem that isn't really there.

The original 3-light (red yellow yellow) testers were useful, simply because they were 3 neon lights each connected to 2 of the 3 pins.  So *just like that* it would do 3 neon-light tests.  They had a sticker that interpreted the 3 lights, and the sticker was pretty useless (all the problems I mentioned earlier).

This *particular* one eliminates the (rather useful) 3 lights and gives you a computer that gives you *only* the (rather misleading) interpretation.  Send it back.

### Your problem.

Honestly, the most likely problem with a "working, but tests badly" GFCI recep is a lack of a ground wire.   On a proper 3-light "Magic 8-ball" tester that would test as "middle yellow only" (the hot-neutral neon).

It's perfectly legal to fit 3-prong receptacles *that are ungrounded* as long as

- a) the receptacle is GFCI-protected somewhere, AND
- b) the receptacle is labeled to indicate "GFCI Protected" and "No Equipment Ground".

[image]

Therefore it's quite possible that *the real defect here* is the lack of that sticker, the one that says "No Equipment Ground".  That is mandatory.  It doesn't have to be the hokey blue stickers you get in GFCI packages.